# callback function for location.href

Tags: javascript, c#

We have below code

**Javascript:**

```
function Download() {
            //Show Loading Spinner
            location.href = "FileDownloadHandler.ashx";              
            //Some Code(Hiding Loading Spinner)
        }
```

**aspx page:**

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="Download();" />
```

"FileDownloadHandler" will download the file to the user.

**Actual Result:**
Code below location.href is executing immediately without completion of handler execution.

**Expected Result:**
I want to stop executing "SomeCode" until handler completes the execution.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. Using jQuery plugin we can achieve this. I have implemented it and working like a charm.

This Plugin does file download and it has successs & failure callbacks, so we can have control on the code which should execute after completion of file download.

Here instead of location.href, we have to call this plugin to invoke our FileDownloadHandler as below.

```
 $("#loading").show();

 $.fileDownload('FileDownloadHandler.ashx', {

                successCallback: function (url) {

                    $("#loading").hide();

                },
                failCallback: function (html, url) {

                    $("#loading").hide();
                    alert("Failed");

                }
            });
```

More details below

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

http://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js

Comment: works if your download script sets the following header "Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Jquery get function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get("FileDownloadHandler.ashx", function() {
    alert("Called Ashx Page");
})
.done(function() {
    alert("Stuff to do after ashx");
})
```

Comment: you can't actually perform a file download with Ajax directly. You can request a file using Ajax but your Ajax response will contain the actual bits for the file. Due to JavaScript security limitations you won't be able to save those bits onto the user's computer with a file download dialog.